# Asp.net - How to introduce scrolling in gridview control

Tags: asp.net, scrollbar

I am using Vb.net for coding. I have a grid view control in which i want to introduce a vertical scroll bar if the value from the sql query overflows. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

You could place the gridview in a `div` with the following style:

`overflow: auto; height: 80px;`.

Answer (score 1):

The following markup should do this. You'll need to change the height as required.

```
    <div style="overflow-y:auto; height:200px">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" > 
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```